# R: convert character vector to POSIXlt

Tags: r, date, time

I'm wondering how to convert a column in a data frame that contains character vectors like this one `"Mon Aug 19 05:00:07 +0000 2013"` into the POSIXlt format.

```
df$created_at<-as.POSIXlt(df$created_at,  format= "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y",tz="")
```

gives me NA's

I followed http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

Thank you!

Comment: It may be a locale problem, as %a and %b match abbreviated day and month name in the current locale. Is your current locale set to english ?

Comment: good catch! it's set to German, to what do I have to set `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "??")` ? edit: `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8")` works! thanks

Comment: You can try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`, it seems to work.

Comment: @juba, SPi, perhaps one of you should post the solution as an answer and SPi can accept it to clearly show others this has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be locale-related. `%a` and `%b` match abbreviated day and month name in the current locale, so if your current locale is not set to english, the `Mon` and `Aug` in your example won't be recognised as day and month names.

One workaround can be to set your locale to english or to `C`, also known as the [POSIX locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html). This can be done with :

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

Comment: Thanks. Now there are only 4716 unanswered R questions. Actually, I think this still counts as unanswered until the OP accepts it :)